# Tokenize text into type,string pairs

Tags: c++, regex, boost, tokenize

I am looking for a way to tokenize a string and produce a list of tokens and token types. Before I waste my effort I'd like to know if boost can already do what I want.

I want a function with a signature essentially like this:

```
typedef pair<size_t,string> token;
void tokenize( string input, vector<regex> match, vector<token> & output );
```

The `input` is the textual input to be tokenized. The `match` is a list of all the regular expressions that denote tokens. `output` will become a list of all the matched tokens along with the index of the matching token from the `match` vector.

I know how to use `sregex_token_iterator` but I'd like to somehow avoid doing duplicate matching on all the tokens. That is, I can produce a list of tokens, but they lack the type information, and I'd like to get that type information without rematching each token.

For tool chain and integration simplicity I'd prefer to stick with the boost regex library and not use a separate tool (like ANTLR).

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you're describing is *exactly* the domain of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html).

Comment: I'll take a look. I'm actually just looking for a tokenizer and not a full grammar parser.

Comment: Looks more like Spirit.Lex is what I want. I'll check that out.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y : That being the case, I would write the tokenizer with Spirit.Lex then expose it via a Spirit.Qi grammar.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y : Ah, I see you're one step ahead of me already :-]